# Updating 'None' value does not reflect in the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, nonetype

I have linked list with the following structure.

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self,val):
    self.val = val
    self.next = None

n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
n4 = Node(4)

n1.next = n2
n2.next = n3
n3.next = n4
```

The last node's next is None , but when update it , it does reflect in the linked list.

```
a = n4.next 
a = Node(5)
print(n4.next)
>> None
```

But when I directly update (without temp variable), it works

```
n4.next = Node(5)
print(n4.next)
>> <<Node Object>>
```

Why does this happen? I thought None is also an object in python and object assignments just copy references.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you set that self.next equals none, that's nice. It returns nice and then you make to be equal to a object? Why? 

`n4.next = Node(5)
print(n4.next.next) `returns None as well

Comment: `None` is a singleton. There's only one None object, so changing the identity of that one object would break... well, almost *everything*. Be glad the interpreter doesn't let you do it.

Comment: Anyhow, `a = Node(5)` is replacing the old value assigned to `a` with a new one; it's *not* modifying the prior object of that reference (the thing `a` used to point to); instead, it only makes `a` point to something different, leaving the old pointed-to object completely unmodified (albeit with a lower refcount, and subject to garbage collection should that reference count now be 0).

Comment: You need to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing the special Python `None` singleton object with a normal Python class instance.

And you are confusing the classic programming language "variable" term (a container for value(s)) with references (variables that refer, or point to, containers of values)

In Python all variable names are references to objects.

So say you do something like

```
a = n1
a.val = 10
```

This would be reflected in `n1` object (a Node class instance) because `a`is a reference to `n1`.

Trying to do something like

```
n4.next = None 
a = n4.next
a = Node(3)
```

will make `a` refer to None first, and then changes `a` to refer to a different object, a new Node instance.

If `a` refers to a Node instance, you can change the instance via `a`

```
n4.next = Node(2) 
a = n4.next
a.val = 5 #this would alter n4.next
```

But if `a` refers to the special object None, None will not act like a Node instance and hence cannot be changed

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. I thought it was easier than explaining several issues for you to edit.

Comment: @progmatico thanks for cleaning that up, I was having trouble explaining pointers in a language which doesn't explicitly use them